# Limit jquery selection to specific form

Tags: jquery, forms, scope

I have a page that has multiple forms on it & I am having a hard time grabbing the values from each to provide totals for the individual tables. The HTML is dynamically generated & I am not able to modify that. Here is what each of the the forms look like (but they will have a different number of rows every time I run it....

```
<form>
<input type=number class="entries" onchange="addTotal();">
<input type=number class="entries" onchange="addTotal();">
<input type=number class="totals">
</form>
```

Here is the function I had to add each form & put the totals in the "totals" box. This works great for the first form, but the problem is no matter which form I enter values, it totals everything in the top form "totals".

```
function addTotal() {
  var entry = $('.entries').get();
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {
      if(Number(entry[i].value))
          total += Number(entry[i].value);
   }
   $('.totals').value = total;
  };
```

I also tried getting rid of the onchange action & trying to refer to each form as 'this' but I can't seem to grab all the values this way, I only get an array...

```
$(.entries').change(function() {
var entry = ($(this.form).get());
  console.log(entry);
});
```

I'm sure there is probably something obvious that I am missing but I can't seem to get what i need here. Any suggestions would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED** Will now work with any number of fields
Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vx403ax0/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".entries").change(function () {
        $("form").each(function () {
           var result = 0;
            $(this).find(".entries").each(function(i, el){
                result += parseInt(el.value);
            });
            if(isNaN(result)){
            return;
            } else{
           $(this).find(".totals").val(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, I will have an unknown number of input fields every time. (Sorry, forgot to include that part in my question.) Because it is generated, it will return a different amount of rows every time depending on the database info. I tried to modify your suggestion to accommodate that but didn't have any luck.

Answer (score 1):

This may be inefficent, but gets job done.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".entries").change(function () {
        $("form").each(function () {
            $form = $(this);
            $val = 0;
            $form.find('input:not(.totals)').each(function (i, el) {
                if ($(el).val() !== '') {
                    $val += parseInt($(el).val());
                }
            });
            $form.find(".totals").val($val);
        });
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle based on ChrisJ comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d9boLc13/

Comment: Once I found out it had to accommodate a different number of fields each time, we took a very similar approach. Nice job.

Comment: This works well too. The only reason that I chose Chris J's as the solution was because this gives me a NaN result when I enter decimals. I changed the parseInt to Number thinking that should fix it but couldn't get that part to work exactly as needed. Otherwise, it was perfect, thanks so much!!

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle too!! It really helped me understand what I did wring to be able to play around with it & not risk ruining my application :)